# will linux emit event when monitor connect with D-sub connector?

Tags: linux, vga, x11

I want to write a software, when monitor connect with D-sub connector,
this software will pop-up, and ask user to mirror monitor or extend monitor.

but i doesn't find any event emit when d-sub connect.
on Windows vista, if you connect a monitor, vista can pop-up a software to same thing.

does anybody know how to detect d-sub connect event and handle it in linux?

thanks lots!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the traditional architecture of the graphics systems in Linux (some direct rendering management in the kernel but everything else driven by a userspace X11 server), the kernel is unable to detect new monitors (because it has given up control of the hardware) and X is unable to detect new monitors (because a userspace program cannot handle hardware interrupts).  You can trigger X to search for changes in adapter configuration with `xrandr --auto`.

There is a redesign of the graphics stack underway, search for "kernel modesetting".  Under the new scheme, properly written drivers will emit a `uevent` for a hotplugged adapter.  Running `udevmonitor --env` should show a hotplug event under `/sys/class/drm/card[n]`.